How to get the right amount of paging on Windows?
I have VMware instance always working
I open lots of Chrome tabs
I have 32GB of RAM
I have an NVMe
I have 5000MBs - 9000MB paging (chosen from Windows Settings) (just used this after having
more paging, and having a Windows crash.. so reduced that in an attempt to stop my PC from crashing)
The PC had around 8000MBs - 13000MBs of paging.. RAM had about 5GBs of RAM available not used and a total of "committed" (as in Task Manager, RAM panel) around 45GBs. Just after noticing this big page file / high usage, the PC crashed and reduced resolution to what seems like 800 pixels and nothing showing correctly and so on. I had to press the Restart button of my Desktop case.

So how do I choose paging best?
What can I do for it not to crash?
Could 4k resolution use so much RAM? If so, how can I best manage this so that I benefit more from the RAM I have.. I don't care a lot about that resolution (e.g: HD is enough - but can't simply choose it because it will look broken)


After years of using large VM, I've now standardized on between 1/2 and 1/4 the size of RAM, and setting initial and maximum size the same to avoid fragmentation of pagefile.sys. Though that works well on the machines I maintain, this setting is a matter of opinion.

So I am confused are you setting a specific size or allowing Windows to manage the size of the page file.

@Ramhound I am managing it, and I am trying to manage it correctly, so that I don't crash my system. Should I increase the paging file, or decrease it? I have a feeling that I should decrease it, although logic would say I should increase it

I am secondarily interested in slowness/speed. I am interested on having no crashes

The best way to avoid crashes caused by a lack of virtual memory is to allow Windows to manage the size of the page file.

I agree with @Ramhound: Windows is very good at managing its own virtual memory. Unless you have a specific and unique use case, you should just let the OS handle this. While this is a direct duplicate, and while the accepted answer on the duplicate does mention allowing Windows to manage its own pagefile, I would simply add that the 2nd and 3rd points probably do not apply to you. The reason your computer crashed MAY be page file size, but you should set it to let Windows manage that size and see if that fixes this.
